# What is the correct way to consume and produce JSON data in Spring Boot from an Android Volley request

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot

I'm unsure how to correctly send and receive requests from both the Android side and from the server side.

Lets say for example, during registration, I want to check if a user exists by checking their email address against the DB.

My current understanding of how to implement this would be as follows:

Android request code:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { //Assume this request is performed on a button click

    JSONObject registrationRequestDetails = new JSONObject(); //Creating a JSON object to be sent to the server
    try {
      registrationRequestDetails.put("email", emailBox.getText().toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e("Couldn't create JSON: ", e.toString());
    }

    JsonObjectRequest loginRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        URL,
        loginRequestDetails,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
              if (response.get("result").equals("registered")) {
                //Assuming a JSON object is returned here, something akin to "result":"registered" if the email does exist - do something
              } else {
                //Email doesn't exist
              }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("Something: ", error.toString());
      }
    });
    loginRequestQueue.add(loginRequest);
  }
});
```

Spring Boot server code:

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") //Want to accept JSON & return JSON
//I return a Map below because I do not understand if this is the correct way to return JSON format - what is the correct way??
public Map<String, String> registerNewUser(@RequestBody final Map<String, String> details) {
    return registrationService.checkIfUserAlreadyExists(details);
}
```

RegistrationService.java

```
//Assume repo is injected that checks if email exists

public Map<String, String> checkIfUserAlreadyExists(Map<String, String> user) { //Should I be returning response status instead of JSON?
    Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (usersRepository.existsByEmailAddress(user.get("email_address"))) {
        resultMap.put("result", "error");
        return resultMap;
    } else {
        //Save email if not registered
        resultMap.put("result", "registered");
        return resultMap;
    }
}
```

Currently, this works. But i'm unsure if it is the correct way to go about this. Can anyone explain what is the correct way to accept and return JSON data?

Also, during the registration process for example, what should actually be returned upon successful (or not) registration from the server?

Answer (score 0):

In programming there is no correct or wrong solution. However if you want to make your life easier handling json i recommend you using APIs for json serializtion e.g GSON. 
  this link is a tutorial on how to integrate and use Gson: https://medium.com/quick-code/parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley-83d6715776f8

this link is the github of the dependency: 
https://github.com/google/gson

Also feel free to search other library for serialization.

UPDATE: 
  A good server side answer for a sign up would be a user with his auto generated ID or a boolean. 
  With the first solution -User with auto generated ID- a null answer means a failure a complet user means a success. 
  With the second well it's a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about Volley, use Retrofit. Retrofit converts json response into Java objects automatically, using Volley you will need to do extra work for that. And I will explain rest-api part too. If you construct your structure like what i explain below, you will handle scaling and adding more endpoints to your app like a pro :)

**----------------------------ANDROID-------------------------------**

**Retrofit**

Add these dependencies to android

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Now we need an interface that are going to mimic our rest-apis in android client

```
public interface APIUser { 

    @POST("/registr")
    Call<GenericResponse<User>> register(@Body User user);

}
```

This is for registration. Here we have 2 classes, GenericResponse and User.

GenericResponse is generic type of class and we use it for both response data and error(if occurres). It is generic type because we want to use it for all our responses which can be of different types.

User is just simple java class holds user fields.

CustomError holds response message and code.

**GenericResponse**

```
public class GenericResponse<T> {
    public CustomError error;
    public T data;
}
```

**User**

```
   public class User  {
    public String email; 
}
```

**CustomError**

```
public class CustomError implements Serializable {

    private Integer code;
    private String message;

}
```

**How to use it to post request**

You write this registration code in where you want your code to be.

```
            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);

            OkHttpClient client = getOkHttpClient(context);
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://yourDomainOrIpAddress/endpoint")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
            apiDicts = retrofit.create(APIDicts.class);


            apiDicts.register()
            .enqueue(new Callback<GenericResponse<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GenericResponse<User>> call, retrofit2.Response<GenericResponse<User>> response) {
                    if(response.body().error==null){
                     // you can do someting with response.body().error.code and response.body().error.message. Or simple show them with toast
                    } else if(response.body().data!=null){
                       User user = response.body().data;
                       // you got your user object back after successfull registration
                    } else {
                      /// log something went really bad
                    } 
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GenericResponse<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                   //something is wrong with server/api
                }
            });
}
```

**-------------------------------------------API-----------------------------------------**

**GenericResponse** , **CustomError** and **User**  is same class we use it in both android client and web service.

PS. **GenericResponse** is not generic here. Simple class.

```
public class GenericResponse {
    private CustomError error;
    private Object data;
}
```

RestController class

```
@PostMapping("/register") 
public GenericResponse registerNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    return registrationService.checkIfUserAlreadyExists(user);
}
```

**In service class**

```
public GenericResponse  checkIfUserAlreadyExists(User user) { 
    GenericResponse genRes = new GenericResponse();
    if (usersRepository.existsByEmailAddress(user.getEmail())) {
        genRes.setError(new CustomError(1001, "User email already exists"))
        return genRes;
    } else {
         user = dao.registerUser(user);
         genRes.setUser(user);
        return genRes;
    }
}
```

**Last words.**

Despite of error message you are sending use custom error codes, such as 1001 for user not found, 1002 for already registered

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would using retrofit and applying a similar technique to this be the industry standard way of making API calls?

Comment: Absolutely yes !

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I'll attempt to solve your problem by using my own personal experience with registering users. Your best bet is to use a serializer like Jackson (example below) or GSON. This will allow you to conveniently create Java POJO's from JSON data and create JSON from Java POJO's. Notice I am utilizing a Builder method, this is just another convenient way for you to build your models for unit tests, integration testing, or in general like below.

Also check out Spring Security techniques, so you can properly encode the user's password, etc. The following would be a good resource.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration

UserController.java

```
    @PostMapping(value="/register", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signUp(@RequestBody @Validated User user, BindingResult bindingResult, UriComponentsBuilder uri) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return BadRequest.of(bindingResult).asResponseEntity();
        }

        if (userService.userAlreadyExists(user.getUsername())) {
            return BadRequest.ofAlreadyExists(USER_USERNAME, "User already exists. Please sign in with different username.").asResponseEntity();
        }

        user = User.builder()
                .from(user)
                .build();

        return userService.save(user, uri);
    }
```

User.java

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = User.Builder.class)
@JsonSerialize
public class User {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private Integer role;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime createdDateTime;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDateTime;

    public User(Builder builder ) {
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.username = builder.username;
        this.password = builder.password;
        this.role = builder.role;
        this.createdDateTime = builder.createdDateTime;
        this.lastModifiedDateTime = builder.lastModifiedDateTime;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class Builder {
        private UUID id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private Integer role;
        private LocalDateTime createdDateTime;
        private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDateTime;

        public Builder from(User user) {
            return this.id(user.id)
                .firstName(user.firstName)
                .lastName(user.lastName)
                .username(user.username)
                .password(user.password)
                .role(user.role)
                .createdDateTime(user.createdDateTime)
                .lastModifiedDateTime(user.lastModifiedDateTime);
        }

        public Builder id(UUID id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder firstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder lastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder username(String username) {
            this.username = username;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder password(String password) {
            this.password = password;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder role(Integer role) {
            this.role = role;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder createdDateTime(LocalDateTime createdDateTime) {
            this.createdDateTime = createdDateTime;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder lastModifiedDateTime(LocalDateTime lastModifiedDateTime) {
            this.lastModifiedDateTime = lastModifiedDateTime;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder applyDefaults() {
            if (this.id == null) {
                this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
            }
            if (this.createdDateTime == null) {
                 createdDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            }
            if (this.lastModifiedDateTime == null) {
                lastModifiedDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            }
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(applyDefaults());
        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public Integer getRole() {
            return role;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getCreatedDateTime() {
            return createdDateTime;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getLastModifiedDateTime() {
            return lastModifiedDateTime;
        }
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedDateTime() {
        return createdDateTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLastModifiedDateTime() {
        return lastModifiedDateTime;
    }
}
```